# Rails App Javascript Unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with javascript in my rails app.  I want to run a simple multiplication function on click when myButton is clicked and return it in an alert.  Right now, I can't even get the JS to talk, and it's reloading the page, despite the code I have...

```
               <script>
                $(function() {
                        $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            alert("hello")
                        })
                })
                </script>
                <form>
                    $<input id="dataToPass"type="text"></input> <input id="myButton "type="submit" value="Invest"> </input>
                </form>
```

If I add inline JS, I can get the alert to work, but when I move the code outside of the html, it's not working.  Anyone know why?  I'm not adept with jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
id="myButton "
```

with

```
id="myButton"
```

Comment: ughhh oh man, it's gonna be one of THESE days.... Thanks. I'll mark answered in 6 mins.

Comment: I usually call `$("thing_i_want_to_select")` in google chrome console to catch mistakes like this (in most cases typo in id/class is messing up)

Comment: we all know and have those days :)